# Forking core eslint rules

Tags: javascript, eslint, yarnpkg

I want to do some minor edits to core eslint rules, e.g. `array-bracket-newline`, or `indent`. These rules often depend on utilities inside `eslint`, most commonly `ast-utils`. So far, i've used a plugin, added the modified rules there, and did a `require('eslint/lib/rules/utils/ast-utils')`, as `eslint` is a peer-dependency anyways.

Since https://github.com/eslint/eslint/commit/24c9f2ac57efcd699ca69695c82e51ce5742df7b this is no longer possible, as an `exports` directive was added to the `package.json`. What is the usual method for changing behavior of core eslint rules nowadays?

- copying out all dependencies would be possible, but both tedious, and duplicating code for no reason (i'd have to trace all the dependencies, and rip out chunks of eslint's code).
- forking `eslint` as a whole seems unclean, as there are a lot of other parts, which depend on it (starting from eslint-plugins, over to vscode extensions, yarn sdks, ...). Each one would need to be changed, or some very dirty rename used, in which the fork pretends to be the original (accident waiting to happen).
- yarn package patching the `exports` away seems really dirty.

Is there some clean way?

---

Edit: my current best idea is forking `eslint`, removing the `exports`, and then using `require('eslint-fork/lib/rules/utils/ast-utils')` on the fork. This means i need an extra `eslint` copy for no real reason, but it's for linting, and a bit of disk space isn't important.

Comment: Have you considered https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/eslint-rule-composer ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it doesn't seem powerful enough, as i can't change the behavior of an existing rule, just add to it, or take away, without using the rule's own analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to require unexported files by their full path, i.e.:

```js
const { dirname, join } = require('path');
const astUtilsPath = join(dirname(require.resolve('eslint')), 'rules/utils/ast-utils.js');
const astUtils = require(astUtilsPath);
```

Note that this method relies on the main export being located in a particular package folder ('lib' in the case of eslint).

Comment: Thanks, this works. Do you happen to know, how `yarn` behaves for such an absolute import? Usually, a file's imports (with e.g. `require`) are checked to be listed in the related project's dependencies. Does it in this case bubble up folders, until it finds a `package.json`, or does it skip any checks, or something else?

Comment: You are correct that when a module is evaluated, the package.json in the nearest parent folder is used to look up dependencies and other settings. This is how Node.js works (if you are interested, [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/f0dcac89c76cf357f4b4a16c93cf0d798dc62361/lib/internal/modules/esm/resolve.js#L220-L253) is the relevant code). Both npm and yarn use Node.js to evaluate modules.